# Why ,On clicking Refresh component is in state of Loading?

Tags: reactjs

clicking on refrsh Loader is animating on UI  and only fetchscripts is called but at first load works fine , on refresh fetchMarketFeed not called, I also removed callback from fetchscripts function but does not worked
Please explain how to achieve this ?

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Loader from './Loader';

type Props = {}

const Heatmap = (props: Props) => {
    const [symbols,setSymbols] = useState([]);
    const [feeds,setFeeds] = useState([]);
    const [fnoLoading,setFNOLoading] = useState(false)
    const [screenerLoading, setScreenerLoading] = useState(false);
    const [fnoErr,setFNOErr] = useState("");


    const fetchScripts = useCallback(()=>{
        try {
            setFNOLoading(true);
            const symbolsList = await getSymbols();
            setSymbols(symbolsList)
        } catch (error) {
            setFNOErr("something went wrong");
        }

    },[])

    const fetchMarketFeed = useCallback(()=>{
        try {
            const expiryResp = await searchFOScrip("nifty");
            setFeeds(expiryResp.data);
            setScreenerLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setFNOErr("something went wrong");
        }finally{
            setFNOLoading(false)
        }
    },[symbols])

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchScripts()
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(symbols.length>0) fetchMarketFeed()
    },[symbols,fetchMarketFeed])


  return (
    <div>
        {screenerLoading==true?<Loader/>:
        <span onClick={()=>{setScreenerLoading(true); fetchScripts()}} >
            refresh icon
        </span>
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Heatmap;
```

Here get symbols api on refresh it taking symbols from session storage ie local storage

```
const getSymbols = async (): Promise<string[]> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const symbols = getDataFromSession(SESSION_KEYS.FNO_SYMBOL);

    if (REACT_APP_ENV == "development") {
      const scripts = getSymbolsDummyData();

      let symbolsList = scripts.map((script) => {
        return script.Symbol;
      });

      if (
        !symbolsList.find((script) => {
          script.toUpperCase() == "SENSEX";
        })
      ) {
        symbolsList.push("SENSEX");
      }

      symbolsList = symbolsList.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
      resolve(symbolsList);
    } else if (!symbols) {
      getFNOScriptsAndIndex()
        .then((result) => {
          const scripts = result.data;

          let symbolsList = scripts.map((script) => {
            return script.Symbol;
          });

          if (
            !symbolsList.find((script) => {
              script.toUpperCase() == "SENSEX";
            })
          ) {
            symbolsList.push("SENSEX");
          }

          symbolsList = symbolsList.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
          resolve(symbolsList);
          setDataInSession(SESSION_KEYS.FNO_SYMBOL, symbolsList, true);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          reject();
        });
    } else {
      resolve(symbols);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your code to address these issues:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Loader from './Loader';

type Props = {};

const Heatmap = (props: Props) => {
    const [symbols, setSymbols] = useState([]);
    const [feeds, setFeeds] = useState([]);
    const [fnoLoading, setFNOLoading] = useState(false);
    const [screenerLoading, setScreenerLoading] = useState(false);
    const [fnoErr, setFNOErr] = useState('');

    const fetchScripts = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            setFNOLoading(true);
            const symbolsList = await getSymbols();
            setSymbols(symbolsList); // Update symbols state after fetching
            setScreenerLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setFNOErr('something went wrong');
        } finally {
            setFNOLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);

    const fetchMarketFeed = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const expiryResp = await searchFOScrip('nifty');
            setFeeds(expiryResp.data);
            setScreenerLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setFNOErr('something went wrong');
        } finally {
            setFNOLoading(false);
        }
    }, [symbols]); // Include symbols in the dependency array

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchScripts();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (symbols.length > 0) {
            fetchMarketFeed();
        }
    }, [symbols, fetchMarketFeed]); // Include fetchMarketFeed in the dependency array

    return (
        <div>
            {screenerLoading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : (
                <span onClick={() => { setScreenerLoading(true); fetchScripts(); }}>
                    refresh icon
                </span>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Heatmap;
```

In this code, we've made sure to update the symbols state within the fetchScripts function. We've also included both fetchScripts and fetchMarketFeed in the dependency arrays of their respective useEffect hooks to ensure the correct sequence of operations and proper dependencies.

Please ensure that you have the necessary functions (getSymbols and searchFOScrip) defined and imported in your component.

Comment: as Iam setting the state setsymbols it is missed here and have both API , the problem is on clicking the refresh only first api is calling fetchscrippts and another not calling

Comment: did you resolved the issue now

Comment: its not resolved

Comment: Check the get symbols api onclick refresh we have symbols from session in env:prod it will lead resolve(symbols), from that emitting out and setting the setsymbols and second api is not calling and added symbols as dependency in useeffect

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-meadow-5nhp95?file=/src/App.js

second api also calling, check it